# Add value to existing JSON file

Tags: python, json

I would like to define the following simple function:

```
def add_to_json(self, json, node_name, value_name, value):
    json[node_name][value_name] = value
```

where `json` is a JSON file to modify, so it would be called like this:

```
jsonToModify = json.load(open(path_to_jason_file)) # path is of the type: "C:/Users/path/to/file.json"
self.add_to_json(jsonToModify, "NodeName", "ValueName", self.stuff)
```

I have searched how to use the `json.load()` function, but I get this error if I give it a string:

[image]

I am not sure on what to give to `json.load`; how can I give the path to my file as an input?

Comment: Please clarify. Is it `jsonToModify = json.load(open(path_to_jason_file))` that is giving you an error? Or something else? When you say "I get this error if I give it a string", do you mean it gives an error when you try `jsonToModify = json.load(path_to_jason_file)`?

Comment: Yes I actually get the error (printscreen) if I give a string to load:
jsonToModify=json.load("C:/PathTo/file.json")

Comment: Can't you just go back to doing `json.load(open("C:/PathTo/file.json"))`?

Comment: The problem is that your JSON file is not JSON.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala what do you mean? do I have to dump it in order to convert it?
I am pretty new to this content

Comment: @trexgris what it means is that it is not conforment to JSON specification. According to the stack trace the problem is on line 149 of your file. For example it could be something like { property: "value"} which is valid javascript but not valid JSON valid JSON would be {"property":"value"}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of reading data from an existing json file into a Python object (a dict), adding a value to the dict and writing the updated dict as json back to the file.  It's cut and paste from an IPython session running Python 2.7.10.

```
!type test.json # prints the contents of the file test.json
{"a": [1, 3, "X", true], "b": {"hello": "world"}}

import json

with open("test.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    print(data)

{u'a': [1, 3, u'X', True], u'b': {u'hello': u'world'}}

data['c'] = 'data_received' # add key: value to data

with open('test.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)

!type test.json # shows file contents have been updated 
{"a": [1, 3, "X", true], "c": "data_received", "b": {"hello": "world"}}
```

Putting all this into a function, here is a version of add_to_json:

```
import json
import sys

def add_to_json(json_file, node_name, value_name, value):
    update = False
    data = {}
    try:
        with open(json_file) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
    except:
        print 'opening/loading',json_file,'failed:',sys.exc_info()[0]
        return False
    if node_name in data:
        if isinstance(data[node_name],dict):
            data[node_name][value_name] = value
            update = True
        elif isinstance(data[node_name],list):
            data[node_name].append(value)
            update = True
        else:
            print value,'not added to',node_name,'since its not a list or dict'
    else: # add node_name as dict
        data[node_name] = {value_name: value}
        update = True
    if update:
        try:
            with open(json_file, 'w') as f:
                json.dump(data, f)
            print json_file,'has been updated'
            return True
        except:
            print 'writing',json_file,'failed:',sys.exc_info()[0]
            return False


!type test2.json
{"a": [1, 3, "X", true], "n": {"y": 2, "x": 1}, "e": {}, "f": []}

add_to_json('test2.json', 'n', 'z', 1)
test2.json has been updated
Out[5]: True

!type test2.json
{"a": [1, 3, "X", true], "f": [], "e": {}, "n": {"y": 2, "x": 1, "z": 1}}

add_to_json('test2.json', 'a', None, 25)
test2.json has been updated
Out[7]: True

!type test2.json
{"a": [1, 3, "X", true, 25], "n": {"y": 2, "x": 1, "z": 1}, "e": {}, "f": []}

add_to_json('test2.json', 'e', 'new_key', 'new_value')
test2.json has been updated
Out[9]: True

!type test2.json
{"a": [1, 3, "X", true, 25], "f": [], "e": {"new_key": "new_value"}, "n": {"y": 2, "x": 1, "z": 1}}

add_to_json('test2.json', 'f', None, 37)
test2.json has been updated
Out[11]: True

!type test2.json
{"a": [1, 3, "X", true, 25], "n": {"y": 2, "x": 1, "z": 1}, "e": {"new_key": "new_value"}, "f": [37]}

add_to_json('test2.json', 'new_dict', 'zebra', 23)
test2.json has been updated
Out[13]: True

!type test2.json
{"a": [1, 3, "X", true, 25], "new_dict": {"zebra": 23}, "f": [37], "e": {"new_key": "new_value"}, "n": {"y": 2, "x": 1, "z": 1}}

add_to_json('nonexistent.json', 'new_dict', 'zebra', 47)
opening/loading nonexistent.json failed: <type 'exceptions.IOError'>
Out[15]: False
```